# Duplicate API Calls on HTTPPost

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, ampscript, journeybuilder

We have added an API call to one of our emails, when activated in journey builder we are seeing the same contact hit the same API twice, sometimes three times ~85% of the time. Here is the JS we are using for the API call, is there anything here that could be causing duplicate calls? Is this a known marketing cloud bug?

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core", "1.1.1");
var lead_id = Number(Variable.GetValue("@id"));
var lead_type = Variable.GetValue("@lead_type");
var key = Variable.GetValue("@key");
var url = 'https://url.com'
var payload = '{"id": ' + id + ', "lead_type": ' + Stringify(lead_type) + '}';
var headerNames = ['api-key'];
var headerValues = [key];
var contentType = 'application/json';
try {
  var resp = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, payload, headerNames, headerValues);
  var response = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(String(resp.Response));
  var send_email = response.send_email
  Variable.SetValue("@ds_response", String(send_email));
} catch (e) {
    Variable.SetValue("@ds_response", String(e))
}
```

Comment: I would suggest looking at _MessageContext == SEND so any calls during pre-build don't happen, and do you have the httppost in the HTML AND TEXT version of the email?